# Why am i getting library not found for -lz.1.2.3 error in Xcode 4.3.3?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3, xcodebuild, ios5

I installed Xcode 4.3.3. Before i was using Xcode 3.2.6. Now when i try to install my app which i made in Xcode 3.2.6 to my iPhone 4S then i get following error:

```
 Ld /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-ezwzjyiebhnsmsgehafwnegjidhu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApplication.app/MyApplication normal armv7
cd "/Users/me/Desktop/Old Data/desktop/UpdatedApp/MyApplication"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -L/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-ezwzjyiebhnsmsgehafwnegjidhu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-ezwzjyiebhnsmsgehafwnegjidhu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-ezwzjyiebhnsmsgehafwnegjidhu/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApplication.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -framework MediaPlayer -framework MapKit -framework MobileCoreServices -lxml2 -lz.1.2.3 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MessageUI -o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-ezwzjyiebhnsmsgehafwnegjidhu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApplication.app/MyApplication

 ld: library not found for -lz.1.2.3
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea why i am getting this error and how can i solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you specifically need version 1.2.3 of libz?  I would doubt it.  Look at the project build settings and add the (unversioned) libz there (and remove the existing libz.1.2.3).

Comment: Project build settings and added libz.1.2.5.dylib and removed libz.1.2.3.dylib

Comment: Link with as generic a version as possible (i.e. no version or version 1) unless you explicitly need a particular version which you won't 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove libz-1.2.x.dylib from library and add libz.dylib instead.